# Passing specific div as child in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass a specific div which has a class name 'message-content' as props.children not all the divs above it. How can this be done?

```
        <div className="message">
          <div className="message-title-info">Alert</div>
          <div className="message-content">
            {infoContent}
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
const isMobileView = useMobileView("desktop");
  if (isMobileView)
    return <div className="message-mobile"> {props.children}</div>;
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code? not sure what you are trying to achieve. Are those two components?

Where does the second snippet gets it's props from?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get your specific div element with:

```
const element = document.querySelectorAll(["classname=message-content"])[0]
```

Then update the `props.children` by adding your `element`

```
React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, element))
```

Comment: It returned also all the divs :(

Comment: try `Array.from(
      document.getElementsByClassName('message-content')
    );`